# How can I remove imagefile from s3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I succeed in uploading an image file to S3 using the carrierwave and fog gems, but I don't know how to remove it.

My intentions are as follows. A user uploads a image file to the User's "sumnail" attribute. The user wants to change the image. The system will remove the old file and then upload the new image. How can I accomplish this?

My uploader name is Imgs. Here is my code:

**app/uploaders/imgs_uploader.rb**

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImgsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    Time.now.to_i.to_s + [*('a'..'z')].sample(8).join + "." + file.extension if original_filename
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/home_controller.rb**

```
 def sumnailUpload
    u = User.find(current_user.id)
    unless u.sumnail.empty?
      # I think remove old image code here.
    end

    file = params[:sumnail]
    uploader = ImgsUploader.new
    uploader.store!(file)      

    u.sumnail = uploader.url
    u.save    
    redirect_to "/home/index"
  end
```

**config/initailzers/aws.rb**

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  #config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:              'AWS',                        
    aws_access_key_id:     ENV['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],                        
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],                        
    region:                'ap-northeast-2',                  
    endpoint:              'https://s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com' 
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'filefile'                          
  config.fog_public     = true                         
  config.fog_attributes = {} 
end
```

=================================================================

### 17.2.6 I solved like this

**app/models/user.rb**
    require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
      ...
    end

**app/uploaders/imgs_uploader.rb**
    class ImgsUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

```
  storage :fog
  ...
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  ...
  def filename
    # "something.jpg" if original_filename
    "u_#{model.id}." + file.extension if original_filename
  end

end
```

then, I used like this.

one_user.avatar.store!("")

Answer (score 0):

You Can Remove image file using AWS Console, or Using AWS CLI

[S3 CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html)

[S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call `User#remove_sumnail!` on an instance of User, and then save.

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
user.remove_sumnail!
user.save
```

See the documentation here:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/17ae595237339ea9372aa4b9144387c5041b32f0/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#L87

And here:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#removing-uploaded-files